# Use fixed exponent in scientific notation

Tags: python, scientific-notation, format-specifiers

Consider the following Python snippet:

```
for ix in [0.02, 0.2, 2, 20, 200, 2000]:
    iss = str(ix) + "e9"
    isf = float(iss)
    print(iss + "\t=> " + ("%04.03e" % isf) + " (" + str(isf) + ")")
```

It generates the following output:

```
0.02e9  => 2.000e+07 (20000000.0)
0.2e9   => 2.000e+08 (200000000.0)
2e9     => 2.000e+09 (2000000000.0)
20e9    => 2.000e+10 (20000000000.0)
200e9   => 2.000e+11 (2e+11)
2000e9  => 2.000e+12 (2e+12)
```

Is it possible to "go back" somehow? That is:

```
2.000e+07 => 0.02e9 
2.000e+08 => 0.2e9
2.000e+09 => 2e9    
2.000e+10 => 20e9   
2.000e+11 => 200e9  
2.000e+12 => 2000e9
```

... I'd specify I want the exponent to be `e+09`; and then whatever number I throw at this hypothetic function, returns the number value in that exponent? Would it be possible to specify zero padding for both the whole and the decimal part in each case? (i.e. `000.0200e9` and `020.0000e9`)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Format it yourself (see [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)):

```
for ix in [.02e9, .2e9, 2e9, 20e9, 200e9, 2000e9]:
    print('{:.3e} => {:0=8.3f}e9'.format(ix, ix / 1e9))
```

#### Output

```
2.000e+07 => 0000.020e9
2.000e+08 => 0000.200e9
2.000e+09 => 0002.000e9
2.000e+10 => 0020.000e9
2.000e+11 => 0200.000e9
2.000e+12 => 2000.000e9
```

#### Explanation

`{:0=8.3f}` means "zero-pad, pad between the sign and the number, total field width 8, 3 places after the decimal, fixed point format".

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Mark Tolonen - I forgot about doing the divisions myself; cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Ah well, got it:

```
for ix in [0.02, 0.2, 2, 20, 200, 2000]:
  iss=str(ix) + "e9"
  isf=float(iss)
  isf2=isf/float("1e9")
  isf2s = ("%04.03f" % isf2) + "e9"
  print(iss + "\t=> " + ("%04.03e" % isf ) + " (" + str(isf) + ")" + " -> " + isf2s )
```

... gives:

```
0.02e9  => 2.000e+07 (20000000.0) -> 0.020e9
0.2e9   => 2.000e+08 (200000000.0) -> 0.200e9
2e9 => 2.000e+09 (2000000000.0) -> 2.000e9
20e9    => 2.000e+10 (20000000000.0) -> 20.000e9
200e9   => 2.000e+11 (2e+11) -> 200.000e9
2000e9  => 2.000e+12 (2e+12) -> 2000.000e9
```

Sorry for posting,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still coming across this years later...

You can use python's Decimal with quantize

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize

Comment: Can you show how you intended this to be used here?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a PyPi package called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that has support for these and many other numerical formatting options.

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="scientific",
    exp_val=9,
)

num_list = [2e7, 2e8, 2e9, 2e10, 2e11, 2e12]

for num in num_list:
    result = sform(num)
    print(f'{num:.3e} => {result}')

# 2.000e+07 => 0.02e+09
# 2.000e+08 => 0.2e+09
# 2.000e+09 => 2e+09
# 2.000e+10 => 20e+09
# 2.000e+11 => 200e+09
# 2.000e+12 => 2000e+09
```

We can also realize left and right zero padding so all the formatted strings have a fixed length. The left padding options control left padding, and right padding can be accomplished using the decimal place rounding mode.

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="scientific",
    exp_val=9,
    round_mode="dec_place",
    ndigits=4,  # Show 4 digits past the decimal place. ndigits can be negative.
    fill_char="0",  # Left pad with zeros
    left_pad_dec_place=3,  # left pad *the mantissa* to the 10^3 (thousands) place.
)

num_list = [2e7, 2e8, 2e9, 2e10, 2e11, 2e12]

for num in num_list:
    result = sform(num)
    print(f'{num:.3e} => {result}')

# 2.000e+07 => 0000.0200e+09
# 2.000e+08 => 0000.2000e+09
# 2.000e+09 => 0002.0000e+09
# 2.000e+10 => 0020.0000e+09
# 2.000e+11 => 0200.0000e+09
# 2.000e+12 => 2000.0000e+09
```