# Numpy engineering notation

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to limit the representation of floating point numbers so that they correspond only to the prefixes used in physical units.

An example will make it clearer:

```
0.01   ->   currently       1e-02  
       ->   what I'd like   10e-03

0.0001   ->   currently       1e-04  
         ->   what I'd like   100e-06
```

The motivation behind it is that I'm doing some time measurements and having the representations as representations of 1000 is much more user friendly. I know that `10e-03 -> 10mili` or `100e-06 -> 100u`

**Update**

For numpy 1.7< there is a `formatter` attribute in the `set_printoptions()`. The solution for which I'm heading for is writing an inline function which would do the formating.
Once set, it the formatting should be available globally.

[Reference about the formatter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: This is known as "engineering notation" and searching for "python engineering notation" will yield some recipes and code for you to use.

Answer (score 4):

If helps, a 'solution' can be:

Use `ticker.EngFormatter()` from `matplotlib` library together with numpy's `set_printoptions`. As pointed out by @TheMeaningfulEngineer's update link, it's **formatter** attribute requires a dict of keys each with a callable value (a function basically). The possible keys are basically the types to apply the format to. Those can be found in numpy's  [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Matplolib ticker don't use exponent but SI units (n, μ, k, k, M, etc)

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker
formatter = ticker.EngFormatter()
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': formatter})
np.array([0.0000001, 0.000001, 10, 1000., 10000, 1000000])
```

which results in:

```
array([100 n, 1 μ, 10, 1 k, 10 k, 1 M])
```

For more on how to redefine SI units, I recommend [this blog](http://forembed.com/engineering-notation-in-python.html).

---

**Update:**

For those interested, [matplolib's EngFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter) can accept argument such as *units*=' Hz', so that after the prefix values are printed with the unit. Like so:

```
array([100 n Hz, 1 μ Hz, 10  Hz, 1 k Hz, 10 k Hz, 1 M Hz])
```

Also, same idea can be applied to `pandas` by overwriting corresponding formatter.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = formatter
```

Comment: This is great but at first I could only get it to work when printing an array to screen. However, I want to capture the printed string in a variable to combine with other strings and print to screen (or a matplotlib figure) later. To do that, try this: Instead of `np.set_printoptions(formatter={"float": formatter}); print(array)` do something like `my_string = formatter.format_data(array[0])` and re-use `my_string` as required :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262302/python-fixed-exponent-in-scientific-notation) might be helpful for you. On the other hand, I would try to create a few "buckets" for values in specific ranges and check a simple condition > (lowest value in range), then multiply that value by a range, e.g. 2e-5 by 1e6 to get 20u. Not quite efficient, but easy.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a PyPi package called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which supports this type of formatting.

```
pip install sciform
```

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    exp_mode="engineering",
)

for num in [0.01, 0.0001]:
    result = sform(num)
    print(f'{num} -> {result}')

# 0.01 -> 10e-03
# 0.0001 -> 100e-06
```