# How to plot tick values in-place

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following produces a plot in which y ticks are `-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1` and their scaling is plotted elsewhere, how do I force matplotlib to plot the tics in-place as `-1e-9, -0.5-e9...` so I don't have to search other parts of the plot for potential corrections to tick values?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
plot.plot([0, 1e-9, 0, -1e-9])
plot.show()
```

Google led me to `plot.ticklabel_format(useOffset = False)` but unfortunately that doesn't have a `useScaling` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the y-axis tick values, format them as you like, and then add them back to the plot as y-axis tick labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1e-9, 0, -1e-9])

# pull out values for y-axis ticks
yticks = plt.gca().get_yticks()

# format new labels
new_yticklabels = ['{:0=4.2f}e-9'.format(tick/1e-9) for tick in yticks]

# set new labels
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(new_yticklabels)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

This may not be the best way, but it works. There is probably a way to do this using [ticker formatters](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) such as `FuncFormatter`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262302/python-fixed-exponent-in-scientific-notation) was helpful for getting the scientific notation formatting correct.

Comment: I used `{:0=.2e}'.format(ytick)` instead but otherwise this worked. I also asked the mailing list but didn't get an answer so maybe this is the only way to do it.