# number formatting, specific number of digits

Tags: python, printing, numbers, number-formatting

is there a way to print `6.5646961e-07` in this format  `656e-09`?

I have tried this:

```
x = 6.5646961e-07
print(f"{lamda_balmer:.2e}")
```

which gives `6.56e-07`

but I would like to have `656e-09`

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By convention the "e" format only has one digit to the left of the decimal place.  I don't think I've ever seen it done differently.

Comment: @MarkRansom I’ve seen calculators with “engineering format” that keep exponents to multiples of 3 to easily think in metric (kilo, mega, milli, etc.)

Comment: You can format yourself as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8262434/235698)

Comment: This is sometimes called *engineering notation*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments *By convention the "e" format only has one digit to the left of the decimal place*, so it seems that there is no way around to write an own method printing the float in any other special "e" format.

Try:

```
x = 656.46961e-09
def print_with_shifted_exp(x, ffrmt='5.2f', efrmt='03d', shift=-2):
   """ x     -> float number
       ffrmt -> required fixed point format
       efrmt -> required exponent format
       shift -> changes exponent to exponent+shift
   """
   str_exp = f'{x:e}'.split('e')[-1]
   int_exp = int(str_exp)
   x = x*10**(-shift-int_exp)
   s = f'{x:{ffrmt}}e{int_exp+shift:{efrmt}}'
   print(s)

print_with_shifted_exp(x, '3.0f', '03d', -2)
print('---')
print_with_shifted_exp(65646.0)
print_with_shifted_exp(6.5646)
print_with_shifted_exp(0.065646)
print_with_shifted_exp(0.00065646)
```

which prints:

```
656e-09
---
656.46e002
656.46e-02
656.46e-04
656.46e-06
```